# Percorrendo array e separando por virgulas

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma array, e com o **var_dump** ela retorna isso:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 18
      'name' => string 'Drama' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 10765
      'name' => string 'Sci-Fi & Fantasy' (length=16)
```

De qual forma, consigo pegar apenas os 'name' da lista e separar por virgulas?
Nesse exemplo, queria que ficasse: Drama, Sci-Fi & Fantasy

Comment: Déjà vu: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318651/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa Oh my! O_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
// array recebido
$array = array(

    array("id"=> 18, "name" => "Drama"),
    array("id"=> 10765, "name" => "Sci-Fi & Fantasy")

);

// string de saída
$string = "";

foreach($array as $valor){
    // adiciona o valor
    $string .= $valor['name'].", ";
}

// retira a ultima vírgula e o espaço
$string = substr($string, 0, -2);

// mostra o resultado
echo $string;
```

Comment: Pode tirar a vígula e o espaço finais com `$string = rtrim($string, ", ");`.

Comment: @sam sim! É que geralmente eu faço assim. Costume.